# Examples of natural isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I am a beginning Category Theory student, and a intermediate Algebra student. Could someone provide me with some examples of natural isomorphisms (in Category Theory) besides the natural isomorphism between the identity functor on **Grp** and the opposite functor on **Grp**, and the natural isomorphism between the identity functor on **Vect**$^{\text{finite}}_{\mathbb{F}}$ and the double dual map on **Vect**$^{\text{finite}}_{\mathbb{F}}$?

Comment: A change of basis makes for a good example

Answer (score 4):

Let $C$ denote the category whose only object is $\Bbb R^n$ (for a fixed $n \in \Bbb N$) and whose morphisms are linear transformations.

Let $D$ denote the category whose only object is the set $V = \{[x_1,\dots,x_n]^T:x_i \in \Bbb R\}$ and whose morphisms are matrices (composition is given by matrix multiplication).

Given bases $A,B$ of $\Bbb R^n$ we define the functors $F,G:C \to D$ by 
$$
F(f) = [f]_{A \to A}\\
G(f) = [f]_{B \to B}
$$
That is, our functors take a linear transformation and yield its matrix representation with respect to some basis.

We can define a natural transformation $\eta:F \to G$ by
$$
\eta_V = [I]_{A \to B}
$$
That is, the change-of-basis matrix with respect to $A$ and $B$.  Since the matrix $\eta_V$ is invertible, $\eta$ is of course a natural isomorphism.

Answer (score 4):

- If $G$ is a group, considered as a one-element category, then the natural isomorphisms from the identity functor to itself are exactly the automorphisms of $G$.
- If $X\to Y$ is any isomorphism in a category, then the induced natural transformation of functors $\operatorname{Hom}(-,X) \to \operatorname{Hom}(-,Y)$ is a natural isomorphism.
- You may have seen the hom-tensor adjunction $\operatorname{Hom}(Y\otimes X, Z) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(Y,\operatorname{Hom}(X,Z))$, for $R$-modules $X,Y,Z$.  If we fix $X$, then the functors $\operatorname{Hom}(-\otimes X, -)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}(-,\operatorname{Hom}(X,-))$ are isomorphic functors from $C^2$ to $\operatorname{Set}$, where $C$ is the category of $R$-modules.
- That last example works for any pair of adjoint functors.  You probably haven't gotten to those, but, as another example, if I take a set $S$ and a vector space $V$, then the set maps $S\to V$ are in bijection with the vector space maps $F(S) \to V$, where $F(S)$ is the free vector space with basis $S$.  Then we have two functors from the category of pairs $(S,V)$ to the category of sets, namely $\operatorname{Hom}_{set}(S,V)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{vect}(F(S),V)$.  These functors are naturally isomorphic.